# How to specify an ISO as the location of root filesystem for GRUB?

Tags: debian, kernel, boot, system-installation, grub2

I'm trying to understand the Debian ["booting from Hard Disk"](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apas02.html.en#howto-getting-images-hard-disk) installation manual.

The process is as follows: I copy a `kernel image`, a `ramdisk initrd` and an `ISO` with installer to the hard drive and then configure GRUB to start the kernel and ramdisk, but also I have to tell GRUB, where is the root filesystem (it should be located at the ISO), so that the kernel could pivot root to it. But the [debian-supplied grub configurations](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch05s01.html.en#boot-initrd) seem to specify the whole hard drive as the root filesystem, not the ISO file within it:

GRUB1:

```
title  New Install
root   (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/newinstall/vmlinuz
initrd /boot/newinstall/initrd.gz
```

GRUB2:

```
menuentry 'New Install' {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
linux /boot/newinstall/vmlinuz
initrd /boot/newinstall/initrd.gz
}
```

Why would that work? Is GRUB so smart to mount the ISO file on the hard disk as root filesystem, not the whole hard disk? Or do I have to `dd` the contents of ISO right onto the hard disk? Debian is vague on this.

Comment: It's the kernel/initrd that loop mounts the ISO once booted, so GRUB is not involved. In case of the net installer it doesn't even need any ISO at all.

Comment: @frostschutz Why would kernel loop mount the ISO? How does it know, what to mount?

Comment: the initrd.gz (initramfs) contains the busybox userland and Debian scripts written to that purpose. GRUB2 also supports loop mounting ISO directly, but usually just to grab the kernel/initrd from the ISO itself, and once that's loaded again the ISO has to be found and loopmounted by the kernel/initrd.

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks so much, frostschutz, your post and this stuff mostly explains it: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Early_Userspace_Mounting. So, GRUB's `root` option only points to a folder, where GRUB stores its belongings, right? And what about the contents of `/proc/cmdline`, does it point to the Linux root filesystem, obtained from initramfs or GRUB root filesystem, obtained from GRUB config? Could you post your answer as an answer, not as a comment, so that I could accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from frostshutz comment:

> the initrd.gz (initramfs) contains the busybox userland and Debian scripts written to that purpose. GRUB2 also supports loop mounting ISO directly, but usually just to grab the kernel/initrd from the ISO itself, and once that's loaded again the ISO has to be found and loopmounted by the kernel/initrd.